# How to clear the content of a Rendertexture?

Tags: unity, rendertexture

I want to clear the content of a RenderTexture in runtime.

Basically I have this script:

```
   void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
    {
        RenderTexture TempRT = new RenderTexture(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, 24);
        RenderTexture whiteRT = new RenderTexture(TempRT.width, TempRT.height, TempRT.depth);

        Graphics.Blit(source, whiteRT, WhiteColorisation);
        if (Gauss)
        {
            Graphics.Blit(whiteRT, TempRT, PostOutline);
            Graphics.Blit(TempRT, destination, GaussianBlur);
        }
        else
        {
            Graphics.Blit(whiteRT, destination, PostOutline);
        }
    }
```

the problem here is: The 2 newly created Rendertextures' Memory is not released anymore.

So I changed it like:

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
    RenderTexture _tempRT = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight);
    RenderTexture _whiteRT = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight);

    Graphics.Blit(source, _whiteRT, WhiteColorisation);
    if (Gauss)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(_whiteRT, _tempRT, PostOutline);
        Graphics.Blit(_tempRT, destination, GaussianBlur);
    }
    else
    {
        Graphics.Blit(_whiteRT, destination, PostOutline);
    }

    RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(_whiteRT);
    RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(_tempRT);
}
```

Now I dont get "new" Rendertextures anymore, but used ones.
It just draws something over a existing Texture, instead over a new "white" page.

The only thing i want is... that "_whiteRT" and "_tempRT" to be "new" ones, and the memory free.

The Obvious solution does not work:

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
    RenderTexture tempRT = new RenderTexture(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, 16);
    RenderTexture whiteRT = new RenderTexture(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, 16);

    Graphics.Blit(source, whiteRT, WhiteColorisation);
    if (Gauss)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(whiteRT, tempRT, PostOutline);
        Graphics.Blit(tempRT, destination, GaussianBlur);
    }
    else
    {
        Graphics.Blit(whiteRT, destination, PostOutline);
    }
    tempRT.Release();
    whiteRT.Release();
}
```

If I use the code above, in the profiler my object count rises and rises (until i get a crash)
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're creating new render textures every frame. That's your problem. Create your static render texture before hand and then reuse it. Although that temp one should work though =/

Comment: well it works for the Memory, but not for the usage.
I get ... "used" Rendertextures. (like used toilet paper)
I dont want used toilet paper! I want new toilet paper!

Comment: then simply clear the buffer? I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @Sidar so whats the line of code to simply clear the buffer?

Comment: `Internally Unity keeps a pool of temporary render textures, so a call to GetTemporary most often just returns an already created one (if the size and format matches). These temporary render textures are actually destroyed when they aren't used for a couple of frames.`

So if you want to make it "white" why not just blit a stretched white pixel?

Comment: Also you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.Clear.html